# How Data Provider of TestNG sends data to Test internally?

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

**My question is :**

How "Data Provider" sends the data to the Test internally ?

What actually happens behind the scenes, so that we get the sent data in the "Test"?.

I am very curious to know that, how data provider and test get connected to each other just by mentioning name of the "data provider", and "data Provider" sends data to Test.

Does "Data Provider" calls the test and passes the data as parameters ?

```
testMethod("data one", "Data two");
```

**My Data Provider code :**

```
   import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

    public class DataProviderClass {

    @DataProvider(name = "data-provider")
        public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
        return new Object[][] { { "data one" }, { "data two" } };
    }
}
```

**My Test code :**

```
@Test(dataProvider = "data-provider")
public void testMethod(String dataOne, String dataTwo) {
    System.out.println("Data is: " + dataOne + " " + dataTwo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources are here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng

But in few words, TestNG calls the data provider by introspection and stores its values in memory.
Then, TestNG iterates on the 2dim array and calls the test method with values of each 1dim array.

Easy, isn't it?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Because I rewrote some parts of it months ago and I'm able to answer if you have a more specific question. But I think a better place for internal design question is the dev mailing list ;)

Comment: Actually, I was looking for the same, which you have mentioned in the answer. but was expecting little bit elaborative answer, like how testng resolve the calls to the test internally...but it is ok, I am satisfied with the answer. If you can elaborate then it will be a great help.

Comment: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1065/files and https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/923/files are 2 pull requests which modified the way to inject and manage params. You can dig around the modified classes to understand the workflow.

Comment: @MasterJoe2 No, I can't: "This question was voluntarily removed by its author" ;)